# How can I filter <li> elements with the same value?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, socket.io

I have a chat application and users joining the room in this application are listed on the left. But it repeats itself when the user logs into another browser and enters the room. How can I fix it? Example screenshot:
[image]
Here is the part of the code:

```
socket.on('room_users', (msg) => {
    document.getElementById("txtRoomUserCount").innerHTML = msg.length;
    TXT_ROOM_USERS.innerHTML = ""
    msg.forEach(element => {
        var item = document.createElement('li');
        item.textContent = element.username;
        item.className = "list-group-item";
        if (element.id == socket.id) {
            item.textContent += " (Siz)";
        }
        TXT_ROOM_USERS.appendChild(item);
    });
});
```